# Curve fitting of complex data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I want to fit complex data set with a two functions which shared the same parameters. For this I used

```
def funcReal(x,a,b,c,d):
    return np.real((a + 1j*b)*(np.exp(1j*k*x - kappa1*x) - np.exp(kappa2*x)) + (c + 1j*d)*(np.exp(-1j*k*x - kappa1*x) - np.exp(-kappa2*x)))

def funcImag(x,a,b,c,d):
    return np.imag((a + 1j*b)*(np.exp(1j*k*x - kappa1*x) - np.exp(kappa2*x)) + (c + 1j*d)*(np.exp(-1j*k*x - kappa1*x) - np.exp(-kappa2*x)))`

poptReal, pcovReal = curve_fit(funcReal, x, yReal)
poptImag, pcovImag = curve_fit(funcImag, x, yImag)
```

Here `funcReal` is the real part of my model, `funcImag` the imaginary part, `yReal` the real part of the data and `yImag` the imaginary part of the data.

However, both fits does not give me the same parameters for the real and imaginary part.

My question is there a package or a method such that I can realized multi fits for multiple data sets and multiple functions with shared parameters?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To fit both the complex function given above, we can treat the real and imaginary components as a coordinate point, or as a vector. Since `curve_fit` doesn't care about the order at which data points are inserted in the vectors `x` (independent data) and `y` (dependent data), we can simply split the complex data and stack the real and imaginary components using `hstack`. See the example below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

kappa1 = np.pi
kappa2 = -0.01

def long_function(x, a, b, c, d):
    return (a + 1j*b)*(np.exp(1j*k*x - kappa1*x) - np.exp(kappa2*x)) + (c + 1j*d)*(np.exp(-1j*k*x - kappa1*x) - np.exp(-kappa2*x))

def funcBoth(x, a, b, c, d):
    N = len(x)
    x_real = x[:N//2]
    x_imag = x[N//2:]
    y_real = np.real(long_function(x_real, a, b, c, d))
    y_imag = np.imag(long_function(x_imag, a, b, c, d))
    return np.hstack([y_real, y_imag])

# Create an independent variable with 100 measurements
N = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
# True values of the dependent variable
y = long_function(x, a=1.1, b=0.3, c=-0.2, d=0.23)
# Add uniform complex noise (real + imaginary)
noise = (np.random.rand(N) + 1j * np.random.rand(N) - 0.5 - 0.5j) * 0.1
yNoisy = y + noise

# Split the measurements into a  real and imaginary part
yReal = np.real(yNoisy)
yImag = np.imag(yNoisy)
yBoth = np.hstack([yReal, yImag])

# Find the best-fit solution
poptBoth, pcovBoth = curve_fit(funcBoth, np.hstack([x, x]), yBoth)

# Compute the best-fit solution
yFit = long_function(x, *poptBoth)
print(poptBoth)

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 4))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(x, np.real(yNoisy), "k.", label="Noisy y")
plt.plot(x, np.real(y), "r--", label="True y")
plt.plot(x, np.real(yFit), label="Best fit")
plt.ylabel("Real part of y")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(x, np.imag(yNoisy), "k.")
plt.plot(x, np.imag(y), "r--")
plt.plot(x, np.imag(yFit))
plt.ylabel("Imaginary part of y")
plt.xlabel("x")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Results from inversion]

The best-fit parameters that were found in this example were `a = 1.14`, `b = 0.375`, `c = -0.236`, and `d = 0.163`, which are close enough to the true parameter values given the amplitude of the noise that I inserted here.

Comment: Nicely done. Sadly, I could only give this answer a single upvote.

Comment: Yep, I agree.  Concatenate or `hstack` real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @JamesPhillips: I am also stuck in similar problem of fitting a complex function. Can you please explain the significance of x_real = x[:N//2] and x_imag = x[N//2:] in answer. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I think there is a problem with the above code, we calculate long_function() for 50% of input x for x_real and 50% of input x for x_imag. Which means our function is not being equally evaluated for full spectrum of x values and will not give true values after fitting.

Comment: I've expanded my original answer. My example should run out of the box.